# How to remove 3 dots after end of line limit

Tags: string, swiftui, text

In SwiftUI,

```
Text("a \n b \n c \n d \n e")
     .lineLimit(3)
```

In SwiftUI, the above code shows output including 3 dots in the end.
**Output:**

```
a
b
c...
```

But my target is to show the output without dots like this -
**Target:**

```
a
b
c
```

Comment: So you want everything after line X to be removed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

implement the following way.

```
Text("1\n 2 \n 3 \n 4 \n 5".truncateToLineLimit(3))
```

```
extension String {
    func truncateToLineLimit(_ lineLimit: Int) -> String {
        var truncatedString = ""
        let lines = self.components(separatedBy: "\n").prefix(lineLimit)
        for line in lines {
            truncatedString += line.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
            if line != lines.last {
                truncatedString += "\n"
            }
        }
        return truncatedString
    }
}
```